# React Native white-space: nowrap width for absolutely positioned Text node

Tags: react-native

In HTML/CSS if you want an absolutely positioned element to expand wider than its parent to fit all its text in one line, you can use white-space: no-wrap

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
// text content of this node is wider than 100px
.child {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The child element will grow just wide enough to fit all the text in one line. There doesn't be a way to do this with `Text` components in React Native. You have to specify a fixed number width or the Text component will max out at the parent width. Is there a way?

Answer (score 33):

Figured out that the answer is quite simple.

Text wrap can be specified with the `<Text>` component's built-in interface called `numberOfLines`, instead of CSS.

```
<Text numberOfLines={1}>Foobar</Text>
```

The documentation for this can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#numberoflines).

Comment: This truncates the text and appends an ellipsis

Comment: saved me. Great :)